# Normal Distrubition Question - How many wires will meet specifications?

Tags: normal-distribution

> Wires manufactured for use in a certain computer system are specified to have resistances between 0.12 ohm and 0.14 ohm, the actual measured resistances of the wires produced by company A have a normal probability distribution with a mean of 0.13 ohm and a standard deviation of 0.005 ohm.

(i) What is the probability that a randomly selected wire from company A's production will meet the specifications?

(ii) If 4 such wires are used in the system and are selected from company A, what is the probability that all 4 will meet specifications?

(i) $$P(0.12≤X≤0.14)$$
$$P(\frac{0.12-0.13}{0.005}≤Z≤\frac{0.14-0.13}{0.005})$$
$$P(-2≤Z≤2)$$
$$P(Z≤2) - P(Z≤-2)$$
$$0.9772 - (1-0.9972)$$
$$0.9544$$

(ii) I'm stuck on this part, do you simply put $0.9544^4 = 0.8297?$

Comment: (ii) Yes, if we assume independence among the wires. Another way to see that your answer is correct is that the number of satisfactory wires follows a binomial distribution. (i) I didn't check the numbers but the process looks good.

Comment: Interesting use of binomial but wouldn't I need to know the total number of wires to do that? if everything I did is correct that's great

Comment: The total is 4, they told that. In other words, four wires is four trials where success is defined to be a wire that meets the specified requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Using binomial distribution to solve:

$n=4$,
$r=4$,
$p=0.954$

$p(4)= [4!/(0!4!)] [0.954^4] [(1-0.954)^{4-4}]
    = [4!/4!] [0.954^4] [0.046^0]
    = 0.954^4
    = 0.83$

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to MSE. Please use Mathjax to post equations as that makes it easier to actually see the information. Here's a reference link to Mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference